# The expected version of the product was not found on the system when install Cumulative Updates in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Hi I have a staging SharePoint 2013 Farm and below are SharePoint updates are installed
Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB4484157) 64-Bit Edition
(security update for SharePoint Foundation 2013: November 12, 2019)

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB4462143) 64-Bit Edition
(security update for SharePoint Foundation 2013: February 12, 2019)

Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4461510) 64-Bit Edition
(November 13, 2018, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013)

now when i try to install latest cumulative updates it shows below message

' the expected version of the product was not found on the system'

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484320/april-14-2020-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure you have installed [SharePoint SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2880552/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-service-pack-1-sp1) for your farm.

Second, you need to make sure you are using the same language between the CU and your SharePoint farm installed language.

Then try to run the .exe file using command prompt with administrator permissions.

It should be like:

```
path\<filename of this CU>.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1
```

A similar thread for your reference:
[The expected version of the product was not found on the system error while installing SharePoint designer 2013 Service Pack 1](https://www.sharepointsky.com/the-expected-version-of-the-product-was-not-found-on-the-system-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

Comment: Hi i have 15.0.5189.1000, and when i check there was previous SP1 installed  15.0.4569.1506

now can i install new sp1 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2880552/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-service-pack-1-sp1)  and after latest CU ?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484320/april-14-2020-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013

Comment: The build number of SharePoint SP1 is 15.0.5189.1000, so you just need to run the latest CU. please try to run it using the command prompt as I mentioned in my answer.